# Set Value of Input (textbox) nested in LI

Tags: jquery, textbox, html-lists, listitem

I am using an existing jsfiddle found on stackoverflow,
which has this div:

```
 <div class='sort-me'>
        <li>Lorem<input style="float:right;"></input></li>
        <li>ipsum<input style="float:right;"></input></li>
        <li>dolor<input style="float:right;"></input></li>
        <li>dolor<input style="float:right;"></input></li>
        <li>dolor<input style="float:right;"></input></li>
    </div>
```

I am trying to set the text of the input , but cannot get it right:

Examples of what I tried:

```
$( "li" ).each(function() {
  $( this ).childNodes[0].text('x');
  $( this ).childNodes[1].text('x');

});
```

Comment: `$(this).find('input').val('x');`

Comment: The input value or the text to the left of input or both?

Comment: if i can set the text of the cell it would be great too please, e.g. change Lorem to XYX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.find()` to travese to `input` then use `.val()` to set its value.

```
$(this).find('input').val('x');
```

To find text node you can use

```
var textNodeElem = $(this).contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3; //Node.TEXT_NODE
});
textNodeElem[0].textContent='XYZ';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following method , using **[`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)** and **[`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/)** methods in jQuery

```
$("li").each(function() {
     $(this).find('input').val('x');
});
```